# keep count in a variable when reading data from read_sql_query using chunksize

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
dbcon = ... # whatever

with open("out.csv", "w") as fh:

    chunks = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name", dbcon,chunksize=10000)
    next(chunks).to_csv(fh, index=False)  # write the first chunk with the column names,
                                          # but ignore the index (which will be screwed up anyway due to the chunking)
    for chunk in chunks:
        chunk.to_csv(fh, index=False, header=False) # skip the column names from now on
```

in above code how can I get count of rows in a variable which are being written to csv file?

Comment: just add a i=0 and every time you write a row you do i+=1

Comment: @Carlo1585 I tried like count=0 before the with open and then in for loop count+=1, but it didn't work

Comment: I have also tried count+= sum(1 for _ in chunks), but its always giving 1

Comment: but you put count+=1 inside of the for and as comment you say skip column for the for, if you give me a csv example I can try it and help but I'm not sure about the content, but it should have worked